# (C++) Simple issue to do with structs and function parameters

Tags: c++, function, struct, parameters

Struct Problem 1.cpp

```
    // Struct Problem 1.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "structs.h"

double calculateEarnings(Advertising aDay);
void displayEarnings(int questionInstance, Advertising aDay);
void mainQuestions();

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    mainQuestions();
    return 0;
}

double calculateEarnings(Advertising aDay)
{
    std::cout << aDay.usersClicked; //debug
    return aDay.totalAdsShown * aDay.usersClicked * aDay.averagePerAd;
}

void takeInData(int questionInstance, Advertising aDay)
{
    if (questionInstance == 0)
    {
        std::cin >> aDay.totalAdsShown;
    }
    else
        if (questionInstance == 1)
        {
            std::cin >> aDay.usersClicked;
        }
        else
            if (questionInstance == 2)
            {
                std::cin >> aDay.averagePerAd;
            }
    std::cin;
}

void mainQuestions()
{
    static Advertising aToday;
    aToday.totalAdsShown = 0;
    aToday.usersClicked = 0.00;
    aToday.averagePerAd = 00.00;

    std::cout << "Welcome! Please input the advertising data for today." << "\n";
    std::cout << "How many ads were shown today?" << "\n";
    takeInData(0, aToday);
    std::cout << "What percentage of users clicked our ads? (decimal form)" << "\n";
    takeInData(1, aToday);
    std::cout << "What were the average earnings per ad? (ex: 5.15)" << "\n";
    takeInData(2, aToday);
```

structs.h

```
    #ifndef STRUCTS_H
#define STRUCTS_H

typedef double percentage;
typedef double USD;

struct Advertising
{
    int totalAdsShown;
    percentage usersClicked;
    USD averagePerAd;
};

#endif
```

Basically, the data is not saved when called by 'cin'. I added a line to print the aDay.usersClicked value and it prints to 0. I am learning c++, so the problem is very basic. I appreciate all tips!

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
void takeInData(int questionInstance, Advertising aDay)
```

into this:

```
void takeInData(int questionInstance, Advertising& aDay)
```

and it will work. The reason is that in your version, the paramater `aDay` is passed-by-value; i.e. a *copy* of the argument is passed to the function. So anything that `takeInData()` does to its version of `aDay` is done in the copy. After `takeInData()` returns, the copy (and the information therein) is lost.

In the edited version, a reference to `aDay` is passed to the function. Now it will *reference* the variable that was passed, i.e. the variable in `main()`. Now all things `takeInData()` does, are stored in the value that is actually declared in `main()`.